# Cannot switch focus between monitors when clicking a space in mission control

Tags: high-sierra, spaces, mission-control

I have my Macbook Pro at a desktop station with a monitor and mouse and keyboard. I will generally be working on the monitor and using the Macbook display for reference material and chat. When I am working, with focus on the monitor, I will open mission control and click on a different space on the Macbook screen to look something up. However, the initial click to switch spaces does not switch focus to the Macbook screen, so when I start typing I end up doing random things in the full screen app on my monitor.

Is it possible to change this behavior so that clicking on a different space on the non-focused monitor also switches focus to that monitor? Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to solve a similar issue, Mac mini with 2 external monitors. Changing focus is in System Preferences: Keyboard: Shortcuts: Keyboard: Move focus to active or next window. I changed the key combination to something easier than the default (Ctrl + F4).

I hope that helps.